# Can't get react-native to build in IOS when targeting real device

Tags: ios, react-native, xcode10.2

I have a react-native app that is building successfully when I run it from react-native run-ios AND when I run it from Xcode, as long as I'm targeting an emulator.

However, when I change the target device to my attached Iphone, Xcode fails with the generic error

"clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)"

Builds fine when targeting emulator , but fails if I target real device?

Any ideas on what could be wrong or general direction to look to debug?

Answer (score 5):

Error is `does not contain bitcode. You must rebuild it with bitcode enabled (Xcode setting ENABLE_BITCODE), obtain an updated library from the vendor, or disable bitcode for this target. for architecture arm64`

If you don't use bitcodes, don't use them.

`Build Settings -> Build Options`  '`Enable Bitcode`' is present.

Please change it to NO.

[image]